# Can the "WHERE NOT EXISTS" clause be used in conjunction with other WHERE conditions

Tags: sql

I'd like to check if one set of IDs is present in another set.

If the query for one of them is:

```
select distinct p.personID

from log L
 left join person p ON l.tableID = p.personid

where
     l.tablename like 'person'
 and l.date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-02-01'
 and (l.type like 'insert' or l.type like 'update')

group by p.personid
```

and the other is

```
select distinct p.personID

from log L
 left join person p ON l.tableID = p.personid

where
     l.tablename like 'person'
 and l.date > '2018-02-01'

group by p.personid
```

SO this "NOT EXISTS" seems like what I need but it doesn't seem to work with the where conditions. So is there a way to me to do this check in a query instead of excel vlookup.

**EDIT: OK so I understand "NOT EXISTS" is not the thing I need for this. 
The example results would be:
Set one returns: 1,2,3,4,5
Set two returns: 1,4,6,7,8,9,10
The results I'd like to get at the end is 2,3,5. The results present in the first query and not present in the second, which is why i thought that not exist might be what I need.**

Comment: NOT EXISTS is irrelevant for this...

Comment: you can use `p.personid not in (other select query)`

Comment: Is this MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Hive, etc, etc?

Comment: Do you want to make the check one row at a time, or are you checking "is the ***whole*** of the first set contained in the second set"?  In other words, show some example data and the results you want from it.

Comment: @Nadeem thanks that works.

Comment: @MatBailie I added an example for you, but apparently just changing not exists to not in worked.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful, as would a tag for the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `p.personid not in (other select query)` in where clause of first query

Answer (score 0):

Small changes to your query, if you're using like, without the operator '%' its like using '=' (which is a specific case of LIKE, in a way)

And you do not have to use GROUP BY if you're already using distinct,
either case works, distinct is preferable in your query

```
select distinct p.personID

from log L
 left join person p ON l.tableID = p.personid

where
     l.tablename like '%person%'
 and l.date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-02-01'
 and (l.type like '%insert%' or l.type like '%update%')
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a general thing for SQL or something specific with the one I'm working with but for my queries "=" and "like" do not act the same way. If I'm checking a string it has to be with like or I get various errors. While the equal sign works with digits. For example in the qury above if I write l.tablename = 'person' I get an error and if its with like it works.

Comment: My intention was that without a "%" you are misusing the operator LIKE. it essesntially functions as an equal sign, in that case. in my answer I treated this

Answer (score 0):

So you want persons who meet the first condition but not the second.

First, assuming your database is reasonable, you don't need a `join`.

Second, one method uses `group by`:

```
select l.tableID
from log l
where l.tablename = 'person' and
      l.date >= '2018-01-01'
group by l.tableID
having sum(case when l.date >= '2018-01-01' and
                     l.date < '2018-02-01' and
                     l.type in ('insert', 'update')
                then 1 else 0
           end) > 0 and
          sum(case when l.date >= '2018-02-01'
                   then 1 else 0
              end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for this I'll look into it.